# Error while installing redis using chef cookbook recipe[sensu::redis], while installing sensu server

Tags: chef-infra, sensu

Unable to install redis using the redisio cookbook. Installing sensu server, the sensu::redis cookbook is trying to install redis and failing with below error.
Is anything missing here

```
Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound
----------------------------------
Cannot find a resource matching service[redis6379] (did you define it first?)


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/recipes/enable.rb:25:in `block in from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/recipes/enable.rb:23:in `each'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/recipes/enable.rb:23:in `from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/sensu/recipes/redis.rb:23:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/redisio/recipes/enable.rb:

 18:  # limitations under the License.
 19:  #
 20:
 21:  redis = node['redisio']
 22:
 23:  redis['servers'].each do |current_server|
 24:    server_name = current_server["name"] || current_server["port"]
 25>>   resource = resources("service[redis#{server_name}]")
 26:    resource.action Array(resource.action)
 27:    resource.action << :start
 28:    resource.action << :enable
 29:  end
 30:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I am not sure if it is the same cause but I am just sharing my solution and hope it will help.

My issue was when I upgraded redisio repo but didn't upgrade my run list in, in my case, redis.json

My old run list looks like:

```
"recipe[redisio::install]",
"recipe[redisio::enable]",
```

My new run list looks like

```
"recipe[redisio]",
"recipe[redisio::enable]",
```

From the error our issues seem to be in enable.rb. And it seems `recipe[redisio]` will set the missing resources correctly for enabling stage. I hope to just change your run list will fix the erorr for you as well.

P.S. I also had to add

```
"install_dir" : "/opt/redis/",
```

in my run list. It seems download and install step will be skipped with empty `install_dir`

Comment: Thanyou Liyan. I got to know that the newer version of this cookbook was having this problem. So i changed it to 1. 7. 1 and it worked for me. Seemingly sensu is now updatrd and has a fix for the same.

Comment: Thanks @Liyan. Worked for me. Didn't have to add install_dir tho.

Comment: Changing `recipe[redisio::install]` to `recipe[redisio]` was sufficient for me, thanks for rescuing my sanity @Liyan!